# Sorting a list of observables in knockout

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, knockout.js

I do not understand - why in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5870/) example I can sort this table when the list is an observable array, but in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5871/) example where an array is not an observable array, but has all of the items as observables - it doesn't.

How can I make the sorting work when I have also made all the array's items as observables?

With this array the sorting works as expected

```
this.allItems = ko.observableArray([
    {name:"Annabelle"},
    {name:"Vertie"},
    {name:"Charles"}
]);
```

but with this it does not

```
var ListSortModel = function () {
this.allItems = ko.mapping.fromJS([
    {name:"Annabelle"},
    {name:"Vertie"},
    {name:"Charles"}
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ko.mapping` plugin loops over your inner objects and makes the properties `observable`. I.e.:

```
this.allItems = ko.observableArray([
    { name: ko.observable("Annabelle") },
    { name: ko.observable("Vertie") },
    { name: ko.observable("Charles") }
]);
```

A comparison like `a.name < b.name` now compares two observable instances, which it can't really do... You'll need to compare the observables' inner values, which you can retrieve by calling them: `obj.name()`.

So with the mapping version, you'll need to use `a.name() < b.name()` instead of `a.name < b.name`.

Additional note: It's probably better to use `return a.name().localeCompare(b.name());`